# QueryDict does not contain hidden form field, gives MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django, django-forms, csrf, hidden

I'm trying to integrate Razorpay payment gateway with Django. How do I get the hidden field that Razorpay automatically sends inside my view?

**checkout/payment_details.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'checkout:preview' %}" method="POST">
<!-- Note that the amount is in its subunit value = 599 -->
<script
    src="https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js"
    data-key="rzp_test_YYUUnrrBMW42iL"
    data-amount="{{ order_total_incl_tax_cents }}"
    data-currency="INR"
    data-buttontext="Pay with Razorpay"
    data-name="{{ shop_name }}"
    data-description="{{ basket.num_items }} items ({{ order_total.incl_tax|currency }})"
    data-image="https://your-awesome-site.com/your_logo.jpg"
    data-prefill.name="Gaurav Kumar"
    data-prefill.email="test@test.com"
    data-theme.color="#F37254"
></script>
<input type="hidden" value="{{ razorpay_token_form }}" name="razorpay_payment_id">
</form>
```

**checkout/views.py**

```
class PaymentDetailsView(CorePaymentDetailsView):

    @method_decorator(csrf_exempt)
    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(PaymentDetailsView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(PaymentDetailsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.preview:
            ctx['razorpay_token_form'] = forms.RazorpayTokenForm(self.request.POST)
            ctx['order_total_incl_tax_cents'] = (
                ctx['order_total'].incl_tax * 100
            ).to_integral_value()
        else:
            ctx['order_total_incl_tax_cents'] = (
                    ctx['order_total'].incl_tax * 100
            ).to_integral_value()
            ctx['razorpay_publishable_key'] = settings.RAZORPAY_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
        return ctx

    def handle_payment(self, order_number, total, **kwargs):
        print("requst in handle payment")
        print(self.request.GET)
        razorpay_ref = Facade().charge(
            order_number,
            total,
            card=self.request.POST['razorpay_payment_id', False],
            description=self.payment_description(order_number, total, **kwargs),
            metadata=self.payment_metadata(order_number, total, **kwargs))

        source_type, __ = SourceType.objects.get_or_create(name=PAYMENT_METHOD_RAZORPAY)
        source = Source(
            source_type=source_type,
            currency=settings.RAZORPAY_CURRENCY,
            amount_allocated=total.incl_tax,
            amount_debited=total.incl_tax,
            reference=razorpay_ref)
        self.add_payment_source(source)

        self.add_payment_event(PAYMENT_EVENT_PURCHASE, total.incl_tax)
```

**stacktrace**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kingmaker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\oscar\apps\checkout\views.py", line 580, in submit
    self.handle_payment(order_number, order_total, **payment_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kingmaker\workspace\blackweb_release_2.0\blackweb_services\checkout\views.py", line 44, in handle_payment
    card=self.request.POST['razorpay_payment_id', False],
  File "C:\Users\kingmaker\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\datastructures.py", line 85, in __getitem__
    raise MultiValueDictKeyError(repr(key))
django.utils.datastructures.MultiValueDictKeyError: "('razorpay_payment_id', False)"
```

printing print(self.request.POST) gives

```
 <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['jmeHeDEeNhaLM591S4113k1nNiXPLlPOT7eO47pqFyweLRw5al5ldrafTQmM9JPR'], 'action': ['place_order']}>
```

How do I get the payment_id into querydict?

Answer (score 1):

The expression:

```
self.request.POST['razorpay_payment_id', False]
```

does not make much sense here. It means that you query for a 2-tuple `('razorpay_payment_id', False)`, but given I understand it correctly, you only want to use `False` as a "fallback" value.

```
self.request.POST.get('razorpay_payment_id', False)
```

We here thus use the [**`QueryDict.get(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.get) function that takes two arguments: the key to search for (here `'razorpay_payment_id'`), and as second parameter an optional default value to return in case the key is missing (here `False`).

Note that in your template you render a *form* in your hidden field. You should render a value instead, for example:

```
{{ razorpay_token_form }}
<input type="hidden" custom="Hidden Element" name="hidden">
```

Comment: Yes, You are right about the "fallback" value. However, razorpay_publishable_key is an API key set in settings.py which I don't want and I want razorpay_payment_id which is sent by default as per this [link](https://razorpay.com/docs/payment-gateway/integrations-guide/checkout/standard/) .

Comment: @abicrazieeee: given I read it correctly, it means you should not pass it a value then, since the JavaScript part will fill that in.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to but apparently, it doesn't. QueryDict contains only this <QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['RrDxoKZldfFPX2VzWhcgCFRUe3DTibL4rcDEeeKx5w1iWOiDeygAMM0MkB2QGzL7'], 'action': ['place_order']}>

Comment: @abicrazieeee: it is not included in the headers or GET parameters?

Comment: When I print out  print(self.request.GET) in handle_payment function querydict seems to be empty <QueryDict: {}>

Comment: @abicrazieeee: and the `request.META`, `request.COOKIES`?

Comment: COOKIES
{'django_language': 'en', 'csrftoken': 'JvD4qG1UUHaRL5Vx0m0nlfQw7ZnF5BA4jgDbgaM6MYwkKRiBiD4HvmZodxMCtZA7', 'sessionid': 'bp60bafqlat2nlnzmdyv979cfg6eujzb', 'oscar_history': '[2]'}.  request.META does'nt have it too.